# Drop and Drag problems with dropping onto another object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a drog and drag exercice.

```
dict[box_a]=obj1_mc;
dict[box_b]=obj2_mc;
dict[box_c]=obj3_mc;
```

The obj I can drag them around and the box cant

```
function test_match(target,obj){

     // if answer is good 
    if (dict[target]==obj) {
        hits=hits+1;


        textField.text=" Correct !!!";
        obj.alpha=0.5;
        // remove drag event 
        obj.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
        obj.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
        // quiz completed, all good 
        if (hits==max) {
            textField.text="Congrats all good  !!";
        }


        // if answer is bad 
    } else {
        //if not good, still remove drag event 
        obj.alpha=0.5
        obj.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
        obj.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
        textField.text="Incorrect";


    }
    //display the score so far 
    score_txt.text="your score is "+hits+" out of "+max;
}
```

This is my code. My problem is that if I take an object and put it ontop of another object(obj1_mc on obj3_mc) it will do like i put it onto the 
wrong box. How could I fix this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that the dopped-on object is one of the valid objects, and if it's not - ignore the result. You should probably post a bit more code, since this only covers a small part of your functionality (the actual test).

EDIT:

Ok, so if you edit your mouseUp-handler to include a check to see if it's dropped on ANY box;

```
if (target!=null && dict[target] ) {
 test_match(target, obj);
} else {
```

That should work (untested).

Comment: I posted the whole code if you could take a look over it . Thanks a million

Comment: Would you be able to help me on the same project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929494/new-dictionary-for-drop-and-drag-two-values-2-questions please